# Blackberry return text from a website

Tags: http, blackberry, web, connection

I was wondering if it is possible to return text from a website to the blackberry device.

So for example you have a plain text website that says "Hello World" on the page.

Is it possible to create a connection to that website and then return the contents of the page, in this case "Hello World"

I just want to save it as a string.

Should mention that i want this through an application not a blackberry browser

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can. Just open an `HttpConnection`, which gives you an `InputStream`.
To convert an `InputStream` to a `String`, just do that:

```
byte[] response = IOUtilities.streamToBytes(stream);
String text =new String(response,"UTF-8");
```